# High quality compression with cuda

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -maxrate 63317762 -bufsize 63317762 -map_metadata -1 -vcodec libx265 -c:a copy -crf 28 -color_range 2 output.mp4
```

into a command that uses cuda to speed the conversion process.

I tried

```
ffmpeg.exe -hwaccel cuvid -i input.mp4 -pix_fmt p010le -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v 6M -maxrate:v 63317762 -bufsize:v 63317762 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

And it didn't work.

I tried

```
ffmpeg.exe -hwaccel cuvid -i input.mp4 -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v 6M -maxrate:v 63317762 -bufsize:v 63317762 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

and it worked, yet it set the bitrate for video to 6M.

I want ffmpeg to guess it based on content up to 63317762 bytes. Like a good tradeoff between quality and bitrate but below 63317762 bytes but also without visible block building and blurryness.

And with cuda.

Which command does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFMpeg does not do rate control. Every codec implementation has its own rate control. Ffmpeg just passes the parameters from the command line to the encoder you choose. x264 supports capped CRF mode. Nvenc doesn’t. You must pick bitrate, or constant rate factor.